# I can not see items in the app bar

Tags: java, android, xml, appbar

I tried everything, I can not see items in my action bar, can someone help me?

Here is my java code:

```
public class mActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(myLayout);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_frontend);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_search, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {

        Intent activity2 = new Intent(mActivity.this, LoginPage.class);
        startActivity(activity2);

    }

    if (id == R.id.action_search) {

        //toast

    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }


}
```

This is my xml code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:background="#DDDDDD"

>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar_frontend"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/right_drawer_frontend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"      android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#DDDDDD"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        >

        //...

</RelativeLayout>



<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_right_frontend"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_right_customer"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_right_customer" />




 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>



 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    //...
 />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And this is my xml menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search..."
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

I have only a "black" appbar and that's ok but I can't see items in it.
I appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have you put `app:showAsAction` as `never` in `action_logout` ?

Comment: @Jas means it will show on overflow click

Comment: @Jigen did you try clicking the overflow icon, do you see the logout item in the menu?

Comment: try changing the `app:popupTheme` attribute of your tool bar to `"ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"`

Comment: LOL, you have a black app bar and your search icon too is black `android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"` how the hell would be able to see your search icon, just download the white version of the search icon

Comment: @Bhargav in another activity I see items, only in this case I can't see them

Comment: Post your screenshot too

Comment: Jigen are you atleast able to see the logout button in the overflow menu?

Comment: ah search is an action VIew, you need to initialise that in the onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: try adding these lines to onCreateOptionsMenu `MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);`

Comment: No I can't see the logout button, now I try your code

Comment: @Bhargav ok, now I can see the three dot menu and If I open the menu I see two field: "Search..." and "logout", how can I do to have the search icon in the appbar next to the three dot insead of in the menu list?

Comment: first let me post it as answer :)

Comment: @Bhargav Ok, I write under your answer, thanks for now:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ah search is an action VIew, you need to initialise that in the onCreateOptionsMenu to do that add these lines to your onCreateOptionsMenu function

```
MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); 
SearchView  searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

To show the Search action as an Icon always set showAsAction attribute to always like this

```
android:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change color of your app bar and it's icon also.